# Continent sized, X-shaped alien

Tags: story-identification, books

I have a vague recollection of this book, mostly the X-shaped alien. Can’t find anything through internet searches. I thought it may be some sort of “choose your adventure” book, but I haven’t seen it on any lists or pages discussing those sorts of books.

Alien description:

- Hugging a water world. Looks like regular land mass from space, just X shaped.
- Exerts influence over its inhabitants. I don’t recall the method or intensity of the influence. Could have been simple indoctrination (not the Reaper kind).
- Reproduces by launching spores into space. Similar to a sarlacc.
- When killed, the alien unlatches from the planet.
- Intelligent. To what degree, I don’t recall.

Other details:

- The only visible land mass was the alien, nothing natural.
- The alien would react when you cut into it (cutting into the ground).
- The planet is inhabited by human children (the ones under the influence of the alien).
- The children view the alien as a parent or caretaker.
- The book is written in either 1st or 2nd person (2 person being the choose your adventure style).
- The planet the alien is on is not Earth.
- I don’t recall any crew with the protagonist.
- The protagonist does not immediately know that the X shaped continent is actually a creature. I do recall that being a decent twist for my young mind.

Upon some further investigating, Ray Bradbury’s “Here there be Tygers” is close and potentially the inspiration for the story I’m looking for. It slunds like they took “Tygers” added some Stephen King flair (the lost boy-esque children) and made it a CYA.

Made a mock-up of it [here](https://www.maptoglobe.com/rJPYKPjfo). In case a visual triggers someone’s memory.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the cover art?  Any character or place names?  You can [edit] any additional details you recall into your question.

Comment: Is the alien intelligent or is its effect on the inhabitants automatic?  You say it unlatches when it is killed; that implies that over the course of the book it _is_ killed?  How is a continent-sized alien being killed?

Comment: I don’t recall. This is everything I know and it’s from memory. It’s a fairly unique take on living planets from what I can find, but it must not have been popular.

Comment: I read it somewhere around 16 years ago from a school library. If I recall anything I’ll add it in, but frankly I don’t trust my memory beyond what I’ve included. I’m mostly hoping someone has read the book and recognizes the alien. And thanks for helping, I’m about at wit’s end trying to find this.

Comment: It sounds like some fever dream out of Dan Simmons's _Hyperion_ saga.

Comment: I may mark the answer as a fever dream eventually. If I am the only one that remembers this creature or book.

Comment: The world is not short of obscure sci-fi, chances are it was a real book

Comment: It sure does sound like something DC Comics would have put out featuring Starro the Conqueror. But those children's books by DC are tough to track down.

Comment: I couldn’t find anything that DC published, but if it’s hard to find like you said then that doesn’t rule it out. I would have expected the protagonist be notable in some way if SC published it, but I remember him as average (not a super hero).